# Build Azure SCIM Endpoint in PHP

Tags: php, azure, scim

I am trying to build the SCIM endpoint for Azure in PHP.
Following the articles from Microsoft is a bit difficult since all of the examples are in ASP.NET

Is there some kind of tutorial for PHP on this matter?
What I am trying is to build SCIM endpoint that will provide the positive output of the test in Azure (Application -> Provisioning). Currently what I get is:

*You appear to have entered invalid credentials. Please confirm you are using the correct information for an administrative account. Error code: SystemForCrossDomainIdentityManagementCredentialValidationUnavailable Details: We received this unexpected response from your application: An HTTP/404 Not Found response was returned rather than the expected HTTP/200 OK response. To address this issue, ensure that the tenant URL is correct. The tenant URL is usually in a format like: https://<>/scim. If this does not resolve the issue, contact the application developer to ensure their SCIM endpoint conforms with the protocol*

and my script (since I just started it is only one file which should output something) is:

```
echo http_response_code(200);
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD Provisioning credential testing does some test actions - GET against a filter where userName eq . The expectation is that a SCIM compliant response will be returned, which in this case would be a 200/OK with totalResults 0. This is covered in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644#section-3.4.2